# what is sensible to debug msp430?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, msp430, debugging

As you know, msp430 launchpads have their own debugger, nothing else required to debug,on the other hand fet-debuggers are sold in high prices on ti.com,what the hack is that? and if i buy only MSP430G2x53 what should i use to debug and make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, you could use Launchpad as a debugger if you disconnect the original MSP430.

Comment: I think you can do it just by pulling some jumpers. But I haven't tried yet.

Comment: actually ,i dont have launchpad can i debug it in another way if it would better choice rather than buying launchpad?

Answer (score 2):

The Launchpad board includes some debugging hardware that allows you to debug the microcontroller using only a USB cable.  This makes it a very affordable eval board for TI's customers because they don't have to buy a special debug cable.

When a developer designs a custom board for the MSP430, they don't typically include the debugging hardware that is included on the Launchpad eval board.  This makes their custom board more affordable in large quantities because they don't have to include those debugging related parts on every board.  But then in order to debug the custom board they typically buy one of the special debug cables.  One debug cable can be reused to debug all the custom boards.

If you're making something that you plan to make only one or a few units of then it's most affordable to buy the Launchpad and design a booster for any specialized hardware that isn't already included on the Launchpad.  (A Launchpad booster is analogous to an Arduino shield.)

If you're designing a board that you plan to make many units of then you'll eventually want to invest in one of the specialized debug cables.  But even in this case it could be very helpful to start off with a Launchpad and use it for some early software development while you're waiting for your custom boards to become available.

It might be possible to use the Launchpad to debug your custom board (in place of the special debug cable).  I'm not familiar with that but you can probably search for information.

Comment: The Launchpads have jumpers between the debugging CPU and the debugged CPU; you can remove them and connect the pins to your custom board.

Comment: In fact, the valueline launchpad have a 0.05" header for debugging and programming off board.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a third party debugger like [this one](https://www.olimex.com/Products/MSP430/JTAG/MSP430-JTAG/) from olimex...  but price wise is comparable to buying a launch pad

Comment: thanks , but it doesnt make sense to buy it,since launch pad cheaper.

Comment: @SOKRATES  Okay, you are shopping for a debugger.  Shopping questions are off-topic on EE.SE .

Answer (score 0):

The value line msp430 g launchpad has a spy bi wire debugger,  a single wire half duplex proprietary debugging interface. It's a limited version of jtag TI developed. It also has limited breakpoints. It may be limited to the value line chips.

The regular debuggers have both spy Bi wire and full JTAG interfaces. More hardware breakpoints, and should be able to communicate with all TI chips using either of those interfaces.

Other launchpad models may or may not have the same restrictions to other chips in their model line.